# Magento redirect

Tags: magento, redirect, localization

I have a store with 4 domains for all languages, so a .nl for Dutch/The Netherlands, .de for German/Germany, ect.

Something strange has happened since some time now:
If I enter the .de address I am redirected to the default store view, in my case the Dutch storeview (.nl). When I use the store selector and choose German, I get to the German store.
Next time I use the shop and enter the German domain in the address bar I am redirected directly to the right store. In this case the German store.
I know that it has to be the cookie, but how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cookie path in system > configuration > web > session cookie to "/" and make sure you have a default store set in Manage stores > Stores .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an extension that can automatically redirect your certain customers to certain store.

Source: http://www.vjtemplates.com/magento-extensions/92-csci2store